# Why use Chrome Extensions for Hardware Wallets?

Tags: hardware-wallets, serialization

Is there any way for a remote webserver to connect to a USB device using serial? If so, why did major hardware wallets use a Chrome Extension as opposed to a backend server for connection? Ledger used to do it and Trezor still does it to connect hardware wallets to their own websites.

Thanks!

Comment: No, there isn't a way to have a direct secure connection. Previously each wallet had to maintain its own API which is in itself very dangerous from a security perspective.

Comment: Ah. So using extensions was a way to get around the API?

Comment: What do you mean by API? The API that the server sends to the wallet? Sorry, I'm just trying to wrap my head around the system.

Comment: For security reasons a web application doesn't have direct access to local hardware, it is the browser and OS that expose certain API that a webapp can use. For a wallet you need to ask for anything related to the private key. For example the Ethereum address or to sign a transaction. This is the API for interaction with usb devices from within chrome https://developer.chrome.com/apps/usb.